Permit wildcard deletions permanently?
To do this for the current session, you can do this:
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "transient": {
        "action.destructive_requires_name": false
    }
}

... after that I can do DELETE ".../dummy* "
... but I want to do it permanently, so I tried this:
{
    "permanent": {
        "action.destructive_requires_name": false
    }
}

... fails with status 400: ""reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no settings to update;"".
Just to make sure, I tried set to true, with a view to setting to false afterwards. I got the same error with true.
Can anyone explain the failure and say whether it's possible to set this permanently?

Which version are you using? In version 8.13.3 that I use it works just fine.

Thanks. 8.13.1. Obviously the next thing is to upgrade. But I'd be kind of surprised if this feature had been implemented recently. Kind of suspect there may be something "wrong" (or rather incompatible with this settings change) in my setup... hmmm

A damm, I got tricked by the auto complete and missed the permanent / persistent

It's not recommended but it's possible to set action.destructive_requires_name settings to false permanently.
The name of the settings is NOT permanent but persistent.
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent": {
        "action.destructive_requires_name": false
    }
}


Updates made using the cluster update settings API can be persistent,
which apply across cluster restarts, or transient, which reset after a
cluster restart. You can also reset transient or persistent settings
by assigning them a null value using the API.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html#cluster-update-settings-api-desc
